# how to translate array information into statement in php?

Tags: php, arrays, xhtml, arraylist

I am working on website that suppose to compare products. So I have reached to this following array

```
Array ( [iPhone 4 8GB Black] => 319 [iPhone 4S] => 449 [iphone 5] => 529 )
```

the key of the array is product name and the value of the array is the price. now i want to translate this array into statements like

iphone 4 8GB Black is cheapest!

iPhone 48GB Black is £130(calculation:449-319) cheaper than iphone 4S.

iPhone 48GB Black is £210(calculation:529-319) cheaper than iphone 5.

iPhone 4S is £80(calculation:529-449) cheaper than iphone 5.

iphone 5 is most expensive product from your chosen list.

Please help me on how to output those statements from an array. Your suggestion to do something else with this array in-terms of comparing would also be great. Thank you.

Comment: i haven't tried anything yet.so far i can only output:iphone 4 8GB cost 319. iPhone 4S cost 449 and so on using foreach loop.

Comment: it's a simple `for` loop and some `if`, I also think it should be a good exercice to learn PHP and would advice you to try to do it alone consulting the PHP documentation of `for` and `if`.

Comment: The output will have `sum(1..l-1)+2` lines, which is `(l-1)*(l-2)/2+2`, where `l` is the length of your array. So for a 10 products list, this will be 38 lines. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: yes i think i want to do this. there is no other way i could compare such an array, is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to sort your array with `asort` (in order to keep the association between your index and your values, and sort on values).

```
asort($yourArray);
```

Then, as your array is sorted, you can isolate price and names.

```
$names = array_keys($yourArray);
$prices = array_values($yourArray);
```

At this point you have 2 numerical indexed array containing your label and your prices and these 2 arrays are synchronized.

Finally, you just have to loop from 0 to the length of your array (one of them, its the same size) and made your process:

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($names) ; $i++)
{
    if ($i == 0)
    {
        // First product -> cheapest
        echo "The product " . $names[$i] . " is cheapest";
    }
    else if ($i == (count($names) - 1))
    {
        // Last product, the most expensive
        echo "The product " . $names[$i] . " is the most expensive product of the list";
    }
    else
    {
        // calculate the diff between current product and first product
        $diff = $price[$i] - $price[0];
        echo "The product " . $names[$i] . " is " . $diff . " more expensive than " . $names[0];
    }
}
```

This example make all comparision to the first product.

If you need all combination, it is a little more complexe, you have to make a double loop:

```
// Hard print the first product
echo "The product " . $names[0] . " is the cheapest";

// Make all possible comparisions
for($j = 0 ; $j < (count($names) - 1) ; $j++)
{
    for($i = ($j+1) ; $i < count($names) ; $i++)
    {
        // calculate the diff between current product and first product
        $diff = $price[$i] - $price[$j];
        echo "The product " . $names[$i] . " is " . $diff . " more expensive than " . $names[$j];
    }
}

// Hard print the last product
echo "The product " . $name[count($names) - 1] . " is the more expensive";
```

Comment: Thank you! i was looking for something like this. YOU ARE AWESOME!!

Comment: In fact my solution make a simple loop to compare all products with the first one. if you want to make all combinaisons of comparision, you just have to wrap this loop inside a parent loop (2 level of loop) and chage a little the test part. good luck